# Android: setTranslationX glitches after view's anchor changed

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view

Using setTranslationX, I'm trying to animate a view as I swipe it across the screen. Then after it passes a threshold-X, I assign the view a new RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF.

I want it to stop animating (whether or not I continue swiping) at that point and basically lock to that new anchor.

This is where the problem is: suddenly the view jumps X position to the right of its new anchor.

I've tried, when it's >= threshold, to set setTranslationX(0), but then I see the view twitch/flash twice, once to its original 0, then to the new 0.

I would love to get rid of that double twitch/flash, but don't know how at this point.

```
@Override
public void onChildDraw(Canvas c ... float dX) {
    threshold = anchorView.getRight();

    if (animate) {
        if (dX >= 0) {
            translationX = Math.min(dX, threshold);

            if (dX >= threshold) {
                translationX = 0;  // (A) if I do this, then mainView flashs twice: original 0, then new 0
                setToRightOf(mainView, anchorView);
                mainView.invalidate();  // has no effect
            }
        } else {
            translationX = 0;
        }

        // if I don't do (A), then mainView will suddenly jump to 2*threshold
        mainView.setTranslationX(translationX);
        return;
    }

    super.onChildDraw(c ... dX);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, instead of assigning `RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF` during onDraw to set the threshold boundary, I took it out and assigned it when my touch left the screen.

But to insure I wouldn't swipe back behind that threshold while swiping, I had to add another case to check translationX and instead of previously trying to rely on the RelativeLayout anchor.

Now, I'm using `setTag()` and `getTag()` to help confirm the threshold during the swipe:

```
if (dX >= 0) {
    if ((Object) past != tag)
        translationX = Math.min(dX, threshold);
    else
        translationX = threshold;

    if (dX >= threshold) {
        if ((Object) past != tag) {
            anchorView.setTag(past);
        }
    }
} else {
    ...
}
```

Plus a couple other places to make sure I reset anchorView's tag and the translationX when needed, then it's all good.

It works for now!

(doesn't directly solve the double flash/twitch issue, but a different approach to the same goal)

(any other recommendations besides using `setTag()`?)

P.S. In my earlier attempts, instead of `invalidate()`, I later tried `mainView.requestLayout()` with no success either, thinking `requestLayout()` also factors in position.